# Change Unity searcher default from "Computer and online sources" to "Applications" Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: unity, 13.10, search, default

I have Ubuntu 13.10 and I would like to change the default searcher in Unity from "Computer and online sources" to "Applications" (Screenshots: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hflgu.jpg) 
I haven't been able to find any settings regarding the default, only filter results settings.
I hope somebody can help!

Rasmus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly summon the Aplication lens with <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>

You can see other Unity desktop shorcuts if you keep <kbd>Super</kbd> pressed.